# SSL Record Layer vs TLSv1.2 Record Layer

Tags: java, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, jboss

I have a java based application. It tries to connect a web server through HTTPS. But, it fails in very first step of hand shake. I took tcp trace. I also check connection via browser. Browser connects successfully, even java fails. I took its tcp trace too. I checked the difference. Even they both uses TLSv1.2, their "Client Hello" messages are different. Java one uses "SSL Record Layer", browser uses "TLSv1.2 Record Layer" for "Client Hello" message.

Here screenshots of tcp dumps.

Java:
[image]

and, detailed message of package of java

[image]

and, browser:

[image]

and, detailed message of package of browser

[image]

Some versions informations:

Java version is 8 (source application, working in 10.x.x.170)
Java application is working in JBoss 6.4 (source application)
Web application works under IIS (Windows Server 2012, working in 10.x.x.171)

Question: How can I force java application to use same protocol with browser (browser looks working).

Comment: Please include in your question the code that makes the HTTP request or provide a minimal example that should work but does not. The question can then be migrated to [so] where Java experts can review it.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/q/747377/219095) looks relevant, too.

Comment: Could you expand the "Cipher suites" section?